# How does Bastion improve security of an EC2/EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

To connect to a remote machine, my public key needs to be added to its authorized_keys. By that logic, the public key for bastion would have an entry in authorized_keys of an EC2. Doesn't that mean if someone gets access to my bastion they will automatically have access to my EC2 provided they have the right host and user? How did Bastion then enhance the security of my EC2? Wouldn't it be equally difficult for a hacker to get his public key added to either the Bastion or EC2?

Comment: The _public_ key, which you store in `authorized_keys`, is not sufficient to grant access to another machine. You need the _private_ key to do that. And you should never store the private key anywhere other than your personal machine.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite correct. It is *not* a good idea to store keys on a Bastion host.

The purpose of a Bastion is to be the part of your architecture that "sticks out" onto the Internet, with the other resources hidden behind the "wall".

In fact, the *Bastion* name refers to "a projecting part of a fortification built at an angle to the line of a wall, so as to allow defensive fire in several directions.".

Just as a castle has a defensive bastion, you should also be defensive with your bastion by *not* storing keys on it.

Instead, you can use **Agent Forwarding**. This allows you to SSH to the bastion, then use the same keypair to login to another computer *without having to store the keypair on the bastion*.

There's plenty of information online to explain Agent Forwarding, such as: [How to use SSH properly and what is SSH Agent Forwarding - DEV Community](https://dev.to/levivm/how-to-use-ssh-and-ssh-agent-forwarding-more-secure-ssh-2c32)

Comment: For a Bastion, it's better to use `ProxyJump` in your SSH config. See https://heipei.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/

Comment: But would it be a bad idea of having the same key for Bastion as well as EC2? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having the Bastion in the first place?

Comment: @KshitijKohli - an SSH key is a unique identifier of you as an authorized system user. As long as you keep your _private_ key private, which means keeping your personal machine secured, there is no additional benefit to having multiple keys. Either none will be compromised or all will be.